# look for element and append a child to it

Tags: java, xml

below i try to look for element and append a child to it ;but what the wrong with it!!??

```
// Document doc;

Element cust = doc.createElement("cust");
cust.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("anyname"));
org.w3c.dom.Node custmers = doc.getElementsByTagName("custmers").item(0);
custmers.appendChild(cust);
```

Comment: are you facing any problems while doing so?

Comment: Please explain what "a right way" is? The easiet, the one with the best performance? What are your criterias?

Comment: it's wrong but i don't know why

Comment: i want to add element (cust) to an existed element (custmers)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid navigating to the specific element, then try using xpath.

**[Link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0540__XML/AppendchildfromXPathNavigator.htm)**

Comment: Sorry this is the link "http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0540__XML/AppendchildfromXPathNavigator.htm"

Comment: @gurvinder372 You can edit your answer rather than commenting on it.